# Call extension method from Javascript Visualforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I've been trying to call an extension method from my visualforce page.

```
<apex:page title="Title" standardController="Account" showChat="true" tabStyle="Account" standardStylesheets="true"  showHeader="true" extensions="AccountExtension">

<script type="text/javascript">
Sfdc.onReady(function() {
        if({!isTrue}){
            // Do Something
        }
});
</script>
```

My method in my extension:

```
public with sharing class AccountExtension {
    public boolean isTrue(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I try to save it, I'm getting the message: 
Error: Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.isTrue'

Any idea?

Comment: You should rename your function to `getIsTrue()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option as it was mentioned Lex in comment is renaming method to `getIsTrue()` - it will be a getter for property `isTrue`, which will be under the hood for you.

The another option is creation [apex property](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_properties.htm) in the following manner:

```
 public with sharing class AccountExtension {

     public AccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     }

     public Boolean isTrue {
         get{
             isTrue = false;
             //implement logic
             return isTrue;
         }
         set{}
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
public boolean isTrue(){
To
public boolean getisTrue(){